# Uncaught TypeError: events.forEach is not a function Leaflet and VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

I am making a vue project and I want to use leaflet inside of my components. I have the map showing but I run into an error when I try to add a marker to the map. I get

> Uncaught TypeError: events.forEach is not a function
>     at VueComponent.addEvents (VM2537 Map.vue:35)
>     at e.boundFn (VM2533 vue.esm.js:191)
>    at HTMLAnchorElement. (leaflet.contextmenu.js:328)
>    at HTMLAnchorElement.r (leaflet.js:5)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="map" class="map" style="height: 781px;"></div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
data() {
 return {
  map: [],
  markers: null
};
},
computed: {
 events() {
  return this.$store.state.events;
 }
},
watch: {
events(val) {
  this.removeEvents();
  this.addEvents(val);
}
},
methods: {
addEvents(events) {
  const map = this.map;
  const markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
  const store = this.$store;

  events.forEach(event => {
    let marker = L.marker(e.latlng, { draggable: true })
      .on("click", el => {
        store.commit("locationsMap_center", e.latlng);
      })
      //.bindPopup(`<b> ${event.id} </b> ${event.name}`)
      .addTo(this.map);
    markers.addLayer(marker);
  });

  map.addLayer(markers);
  this.markers = markers;
},
removeEvent() {
  this.map.removeLayer(this.markers);
  this.markers = null;
}
},
mounted() {
const map = L.map("map", {
  contextmenu: true,
  contextmenuWidth: 140,
  contextmenuItems: [
    {
      text: "Add Event Here",
      callback: this.addEvents
    }
  ]
}).setView([0, 0], 1);

L.tileLayer("/static/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  maxZoom: 4,
  minZoom: 3,
  continuousWorld: false,
  noWrap: true,
  crs: L.CRS.Simple
}).addTo(map);
this.map = map;
}
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

New2Dis,

Here is your example running in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cy1hrevz/2/).

```
  computed: {
    events: function () {
        return this.store.events;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    events: function (val) {
      this.removeEvents();    
      this.addEvents(val);
    }
    },
    methods: {
    addEvents(events) {
        console.log("hoi")
      const map = this.map;
      const markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
      const store = this.$store;

      events.forEach(event => {
        let marker = L.marker(event.latlng, { draggable: true })
          .on("click", el => {
            //store.commit("locationsMap_center", event.latlng);
          })
          .bindPopup(`<b> ${event.id} </b> ${event.name}`)
          .addTo(this.map);
        markers.addLayer(marker);
      });

      map.addLayer(markers);
      this.markers = markers;
    },
    removeEvents() {
        if (this.markers != null) {
        this.map.removeLayer(this.markers);
        this.markers = null;
      }
    }
  },
```

I did replace some things to make it works, like the $store as I don't have it, and removeEvent was not written correctly, so I'm not sure what I actually fixed...

I have also created a plugin to make it easy to use Leaflet with Vue.
You can find it [here](https://github.com/KoRiGaN/Vue2Leaflet)
You will also find a plugin for Cluster group [here](https://github.com/jperelli/vue2-leaflet-markercluster)

Give it a try and let me know what you think.